# Post form to server and render page

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I would like to post a form to an endpoint so it's processed on the server-side and render a +page.svelte with the same submitted data:
[image]

I was thinking to use a +page.server.js page to intercept the form submission via a form action, perform the server-side logic and then use the load function to pass the data to the +page.svelte within the same folder:

**+page.server.js**:

```js
let requestData

export const actions = {
    default: async ({ request }) => {
        // Server-side code here...
        requestData = await request.formData()  // example {"id": "12345"}
    }
}

export const load = async() => {
    return requestData
}
```

**+page.svelte:**

```
<script>
    export let data
    console.log(data)
</script>
```

Unfortunately this does not work since the load function is executed first, so the requestData is invalid.

What is the correct way to do it?
I would prefer avoid having to fetch data from the +page.svelte if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The intended workflow is to use `load` to get data that exists on the server/some other service and for form actions to modify said data. You should *not* try to add local state in the server file, the data should instead be stored in an independent storage like a database.

When using a the [`enhance` action](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions#progressive-enhancement-use-enhance), the page data will automatically be invalidated and `load` will be called again to get the updated data.

Comment: So according to your answer the correct way would be to execute the actions in sequence:

1. the /upload_map/+page.svlete submits the data to an endpoint (that saves it to a file server or a DB) and returns a unique ID

2. the /upload_map/+page.svlete submits the form to the /render_map route with the unique ID

3. the /render_map/+page.server.js load function fetches the data via the unique ID 

But the question remains: is this last point 3 possible? How can the +page.server.js load function receive the unique ID it needs to fetch the correct data?

Comment: If you want to show a specific data point, you should [throw a `redirect`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#redirects) in the form action, redirecting to a [route with a parameter](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing) that contains the ID. The `load` function has access to such parameters via the `params` property of the event object.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the form data from a simple form in *src/routes/+page.svelte*

```
<form method="POST" action="/posttest">
  <label>Email<input name="email" type="email" /></label>
  <button>Log in</button>
</form>
```

from the route in the action */posttest* by creating a file *src/routes/postdata/+page.server.js* and extracting the form data you want to pass on

```
export const actions = {
  default: async (event) => {
    const data = await event.request.formData();
    let email = data.get('email')
    return {email:email}
  }
};
```

Which can then be accessed from *form* in *src/routes/postdata/+page.svelte*

```
<script>
  export let form;
</script>

{#if form?.email}
  You sent {form?.email} in your form
{/if}
```